# Will a change of Nameservers affect glue records?

Tags: nameserver

I need to change nameservers, but need to keep glue records as the are, If I change my domain's main nameservers will that affect my child (glue records)?

Answer (score 2):

The glue `A` records for you domain `example.com.` on the parent zone `com.` **needs** to match your `NS` records i.e. `ns1.example.com. A` must be same on both. Probably your registrar won't allow other glue records than those for your nameservers, and most update them automatically during `NS` modifications.

If your zone has glue records for its own subzones `ns1.sub.example.com. A`, they won't be affected when glue records on the parent zone changes, as you don't have such records there, anyway.